# Keycloak hiding client in application page

Tags: client, keycloak, keycloak-services, application-server, keycloak-settings

In keycloak we have 3 clients name redmine ,jenkins,openOffice we need to create two users one user should get access for all clients and one more user should  access only jenkins and remine  how can we do this in keycloak by using groups.
I have done created two users and assigned jenkins-group and redmine-group my issue is if i login using redmine client user credentials i should not display jenkins client related links in application page so can u tell me how to do this.

I have tried by assigning roles to the respective clients. When i try to login using redmine user credentials still am able to see jenkins client relate links also in application page. We need to hide other client links in application page.